# If $X$ is a reflexive Banach space, how can one be sure that there exists limit point in $X$ to a weakly convergent sequence?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I think the title says most of my question. If anyone has a hint they want to share it would really be appreciated.

**Update:** To specify my concerns, I looked specifically at the top answer on this thread:

[limit of a weakly convergent sequence in Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009878/limit-of-a-weakly-convergent-sequence-in-banach-spaces)

in which the poster simply stated that it can be concluded that the limit lies in $X$, given that it is reflexive, however without any reasoning or similar. I can't find anything in my literature and I am trying to prove it at the moment, but don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a weakly convergent sequence has to converge to a point in $X$ (Note that weak topology is in general not metrizable, so we cannot disucss Cauchy sequences that *should* converge but only sequences that *indeed* converge.)

The question/answer you are reading is different, where it doesn't assume $x_n$ weakly converges, but only $x_n$ pointwisely converges as functionals on $X^*$. As the author put it, this can be used to show that $x_n$ converges to something in $X^{**}$ under the natural embedding $X\hookrightarrow X^{**}$. If $X$ is reflexive, then $X\cong X^{**}$, hence the limit is not only in the bidual but $X$ itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe I am closer to understanding. By reflexivity, we have $X = X^{**}$ wherefore, by bijection, for any $y \in X^{**}$ we are able to find a $x \in X$ such that $\mathcal{A}x = y$ for some operator. Is this a step forward? I am quite new to the topic, however I am currently studying the notions you presented.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right.

Comment: I'm not following. What is $\mathcal A$?

Comment: Okey scratch the last part (I deleted it), however I am thinking that if $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ weakly, we have for any linear functional $f \in X^*$ that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$. From here I am a bit unsure, but must there not be a function in the double-dual space? I mean if we have a map $\mathcal{A}:X \rightarrow X^{**}$ then $\mathcal{A}x=h_x \in X^{**}$ where $h_x(f)=f(x)$ for any $f \in X^{*}$?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are overthinking. If $x_n\rightarrow x$ weakly, that by definition already means $x\in X$. And we may think of $x$ as in $X^{**}$ because $X\hookrightarrow X^{**}$, but this is irrelevant in the context.

Comment: So if $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ we have $h_{x_n}(f) \rightarrow h_x(f)$ for any $f$ and one can perhaps simplify it like $h_{x_n} \rightarrow h_x$. So, for any $f$ and any $\varepsilon$ we may find an $n>N$ such that $|h_{x_n}-h_x| < \varepsilon$ and perhaps draw the conclusion that $h_x \in X^{**}$? Edit: but then the norm is wrong...

Comment: Okey, one step closer I guess. Perhaps I am overthinking it, I am quite unsure. Edit: thank you for your input also, forgot to say that. Learning a lot here